# Adding New Lines to WordPress Post

Tags: php, wordpress

First off I have gone through this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website. I cannot use this.

I am trying to get the latest post from a WordPress installation on a remote server I own. They share the same database server so that is where I am taking the post now and then brining it back into my PHP app. This all works.

What doesn't work is the display. Before I was using `nl2br` to make new lines but this does not work right.

I have noticed that WordPress does some post-processing to add `p` tags to certain lines they consider should be paragraphs (not in `ul`s or `li`s for example). They do this after grabbing the post from the DB (the `p` tags are not saved to DB).

I have tried to find out what post-processing they use in the source code but I have come up blank after finding the `the_content` function etc and where the `$post` var comes from but not finding the code I am looking for.

What post-processing function does WordPress use to add these paragraphs to make their posts look ok?

### Edit

For regex or general PHP people here I am looking to change something like:

```
<em><a href="link">awesome link</a></em>
<h3>Awesome Head</h3>
lalalaalal
<ul>
<li>Awesome li</li>
</ul>
```

Into something like:

```
<p>
    <em><a href="link">awesome link</a></em>
</p>
<h3>Awesome Head</h3>
<p>lalalaalal</p>
<ul>
<li>Awesome li</li>
</ul>
```

Missing out tags that obviously should not have `p` tags around them like `h` and `ul` and `li` tags.

Comment: If you are displaying a single post on another website, can't you just do a query and access the entry directly from the db?

Comment: @DainisAbols That is what I am doing. The problem is the display of new lines on that post. WordPress uses a post-processing function that I cannot find.

Comment: It looks like the _Wordpress modified_ TinyMCE editor is causing the line break behaviour, and not the php code. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L513

Comment: @desbest Though that's the weird thing because this line break behaviour is also present when, of course, displaying the post but: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/post-template.php#L180 I can't see such behaviour within the trail on the template pages.

Comment: @desbest And of course the TinyMCE editor is not used on those display pages, only the edit pages so I cannot see how the `p` tags are related to TinyMCE

Comment: Could you not just access the rss feed (www.mydomain.com/feed) and process that? - The feed will contain all the markup and may be an easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest, fastest way: parse the latest post from the RSS feed. You'll find all of the `<p>` tags automatically added for you.

Comment: Thanks, In the end I didn't want to (also didn't have the time) create an entire XML parser to read an RSS feed so I just built a quick regex from observing WPs own behaviour. It seems to work, +1 for stating how this should be recoded.

Comment: Er, there are lots of libraries to read RSS/XML out there, so writing your own (while fun) is not strictly necessary. For example, [XML_RSS](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.xml.xml-rss.php) works fine and sounds like it will cover what you're looking for.

Comment: Yea it had to be a quick fix. I was really looking for the function they use themselves, I couldn't find the function though. My fix was quicker than setting up a whole new data source through either my own XML reader or a pre-made one since I already had the data just had to run the regex on it.

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do would be as @BryanH said: use the RSS feed which already has the post pre-formatted for you.

However if you don't want to make an XML parser and deal with all the stuff that comes with it just to get a blog post then you can use something like:

```
$content = preg_split('/\\r?\\n/', str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $post->content));

foreach($content as $line){
    if(strlen(trim($line)) > 0){
        $line = trim($line);
        if(!preg_match('/^(<|<\/)(ul|li|div|h[1-6])/', $line)){
            echo '<p>'.$line.'</p>';
        }else{
            echo $line;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I personally used to solve this problem in the end.

There is probably a more robust and elegant way of doing this (quickly coded) however I tested this on a very complex blog post with images and lots of different tags and it seemed to work nicely without any errors.

I am still unsure what WP uses but this solves my problem in the end.